# make ul float right but still have bottom border take up whole page

Tags: css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mpewmo

html

```
      <ul class="slds-tabs--default__nav">
        <li clasd="slds-tabs--default__item slds-active"><a className="slds-tabs--default__link">Date Created</a></li>
        <li class="slds-tabs--default__item"><a className="slds-tabs--default__link">Title</a></li>
        <li class="slds-tabs--default__item"><a className="slds-tabs--default__link">Total Responses</a></li>
      </ul>
```

css

```
li {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.slds-tabs--default__nav {
 display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-align: start;
align-items: flex-start;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

When you make it float right the border only takes up a tiny part of the page. Not sure what my options are to maintain the bottom border and still float right.

Comment: Do you have to float the menu? If you add `justify-content: flex-end` the links are on the right and the border still spans the screen. http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/qrNdPJ If you want to float the element, a common way to pull this off is to have the nav in another element and apply the border to the parent element instead http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/ZeOGaa

Comment: those work. The justify-content worked perfectly for my situation. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, wasn't sure if that was what you were going for or not. I'll submit as an answer if you like.

Comment: yup, you deserver the credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your existing markup, you can put the links on the right and maintain the parent element's width by using `justify-content: flex-end;`

```css
li {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.slds-tabs--default__nav {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slds-tabs--default__nav">
  <li clasd="slds-tabs--default__item slds-active"><a className="slds-tabs--default__link">Date Created</a></li>
  <li class="slds-tabs--default__item"><a className="slds-tabs--default__link">Title</a></li>
  <li class="slds-tabs--default__item"><a className="slds-tabs--default__link">Total Responses</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want to float the element, a common way to pull this off is to have the nav in another element and apply the border to the parent element instead

```css
li {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.slds-tabs--default__nav {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  float: right;
}

header {
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="slds-tabs--default__nav">
    <li clasd="slds-tabs--default__item slds-active"><a className="slds-tabs--default__link">Date Created</a></li>
    <li class="slds-tabs--default__item"><a className="slds-tabs--default__link">Title</a></li>
    <li class="slds-tabs--default__item"><a className="slds-tabs--default__link">Total Responses</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```